# Block special characters but allow spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to block the special characters in input, but my code in Chrome does not allow typing space between words, in Firefox works normally.

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z\b]+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which: event.charCode);
 if (!regex.test(key)) 
 {
     event.preventDefault();
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just add the space to the RegExp?

Code would become something like:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z \b]+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which: event.charCode);
if (!regex.test(key)) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment, tamas

Comment: Just a click-and-play example that supports your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found this method while trying to take input in a Name field. I wanted to allow alphabets and spaces but not numbers and special characters. Here is what I did.

```js
try {
 if (window.event) {
  var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
}
 else if (e) {
  var charCode = e.which;
}
 else { return true; }
  if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 
   123 ) || (charCode > 31 && charCode < 33))
   return true;
 else
   return false;
}
catch (err) {
 alert(err.Description);
}
}
```

Space has charCode 32 and I added a condition to allow character with value greater than 31 and less than 33. I tried = and != too but did not help.
This code worked fine for me.
Happy Coding.

Comment: Best answer for this particular case!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach other than checking each entered value is to check value after entering whole string.

```js
document.getElementById("ok").onclick = function() {
  var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z\b ]+$");
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").value;
  if (regex.exec(str) == null) {
    alert("Not good.");
    document.getElementById("demo").value = null;
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Good");
    // Do whatever you want.
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="demo">
<input type="button" id="ok" value="Validate">
```